# Pandas / Numpy | Restructure an excel spreadsheet

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, loops

There are 50+ 'URL' columns and most of them are empty, but I want to iterate through those columns and grab cell values that are not empty. Those values would then be stored in a new column. How could I do so?

Here's where my thinking has been:

## Import Pandas and create dataframe

`import pandas as pd`
`import numpy as np`
`df = pd.read_csv("Original.csv")`

## Create List of Just URL Columns

`URL_col = MRB[['URL 2','URL 3','URL 4','Fact URL','Fact URL 2','Fact URL 3','Fact URL 4',`
`'Fact URL 5','Fact URL 6','Fact URL 7','Fact URL 8','Stories URL','Stories URL 2',`
`'Stories URL 3','Stories URL 4','Stories URL 5','Stories URL 6',`
`'Stories URL 7','Stories URL 8','Content URL 1','Content URL 2','Content URL 3',`
`'Product URL','Release URL','Release URL 2','Release URL 3','Release URL 4',`
`'Release URL 5','Release URL 6','Release URL 7','Release URL 8','America URL','America URL                   2','America URL 3','America URL 4','America URL 5','America URL 6','America URL 7','America Counts URL 8',`
`'Blog URL','Blog URL 2','Blog URL 3','Blog URL 4','Blog URL 5','Blog URL 6',`
`'Blog URL 7','Blog URL 8','Graphic URL']]`
`#print(URL_col)`

#Create list to store all not null URL values

`URL_vals = []`

#Iterate through URL columns to get values and put in list

`for i in URL_col:`

`value = URL_col.at[i]`

`if #numpy.isnan(value)`

`URL_vals.append(i)`

`else:`

`i++`

Answer (score 0):

You have a data frame and you want to get all values that are not NaN. Convert to values, flatten, and then filter for NaN:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, np.nan], 'B': [np.nan, 3, 4]})
l = df.values.flatten()
l[~np.isnan(l)]
```

> ```
> array([1., 2., 3., 4.])
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I received error "TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''